# joomla dev database gives wrong special chars UTF8 Unicode

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I tray to get data out of the database. That's no problem. But special chars like è change to Ã¨    ë change to Ã« ..

The database has the right chars. Rsform in the backend shows the right char. This is how i get the data out of the database for use in a plugin.

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $query
    ->select(array('SubmissionID','FieldName','FieldValue'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submission_values'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('FormId')." = 4")
    ->where($db->quoteName('SubmissionID')." > 10928");

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();


    foreach ($rows as $row) {var_dump($row);};
```

Comment: Did you make sure your script is UTF-8 encoded (UTF-8 without BOM)?

Comment: Your page render as Windows-1252 (ISO-8859-1). You should set it to UTF-8.

Comment: @Michas how do you know that his page renders as ISO-8859-1? Would  be interesting to know.

Comment: '  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />' this is set..  database 'MySQL connection collation Documentation:utf8_general_ci'

Comment: i manual add this to the string '$html = "<meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />

    <div class=\"page\">

" '
now it work still don't understand why i need to add that meta again in it

Comment: @hherger The string èë saved as UTF-8 will be rendered Ã¨Ã« if opened as Windows-1252. I think these are two most common encodings on the Internet. Using the wrong one is a very common problem.

Comment: I agree. The problem often is that the code is not **converted** (some editors can, some not) but is only **saved as**.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will probably not work, but let's give a try ;)

I had a similar issue with Ohana and Ark Editor... for my part it was created by my PHP configuration. By comparing two servers configurations with the same Joomla components, I discovered that « apm » was wrongfully selected in my PHP configuration.

I hope that will help you.